# Using python-requests with Django's LiveServerTestCase fails with 502

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I am attempting to integrate a 3rd party app which uses python-requests to fetch urls it parses from templates.

I am trying to use a LiveServerTestCase to test the integration.  Oddly, curl works but the requests test `test_requests_static_file` fails with:

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 502 Server Error: Connection refused for url: http://localhost:35819/static/testapp/style.css
```

Any ideas here?

```
import subprocess

import requests
from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase


class LiveServerTests(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
    def test_curl_static_file(self):
        output = subprocess.check_output(["curl", '%s%s' % (self.live_server_url, '/static/testapp/style.css')])
        self.assertIn('background: blue', output)
        
    def test_requests_static_file(self):
        response = requests.get('%s%s' % (self.live_server_url, '/static/testapp/style.css'))
        response.raise_for_status()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going to delete the question but figured it might be of use to some poor soul.  As it turns out, this issue was due to requests attempting to use a network proxy for the connection to localhost.

Verified with this test:

```
from requests.utils import should_bypass_proxies as requests_should_bypass_proxies


class LiveServerTests(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
    def test_requests_should_bypass_proxies_for_liveserver(self):
        self.assertTrue(requests_should_bypass_proxies(self.live_server_url, None))
```

The solution was to use the `NO_PROXY` environment variable.  Something to the following effect will work:

```
import os

os.environ['NO_PROXY'] = 'localhost'
```